# Sort multiple file unix and save

Tags: unix

How do I sort multiple files using unix and save the  result in the respective files?

Example:

If I have two files abc.txt and xyz.txt

```
cat abc.txt
3
2
1

cat xyz.txt
100
99
98
```

Is it possible to sort both the files and save the result in them respectively without writing two command?

That is:

```
sort abc.txt -o abc.txt
```

Is this possible for both the files in a single  command.

Comment: you can use for-loop if there are multiple files.. something like `for f in *.txt; do sort -n "$f" -o "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Do not over complicate. Its as easy as  :

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort
```

Regards. :)

Comment: But this would give me combined sorted result of both the files which I can of course store it in another file. But what I want is to sort file1.txt and store the result in file1.txt itself and same with the other file, not to combine the data from same file. And do this with single command.

Comment: Oh sorry. So you want just simply sort each individual file. Then use @Sundeep reply. Did that work for you?